# Adding a custom header to ARR requests

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, iis-arr

I'm running a service behind IIS using ARR as a reverse proxy.  I know there are `x-forwarded-for` and `x-arr-log-id` headers that are passed along.  However, what I would like is a private key passed in so that the backing application explicitly knows that the request is not local (even though the ARR server is).  I've seen some posts on adding/replacing server variables, but this doesn't seem to come through via the request headers on the backing application.

I'm guessing that there must be some web.config setting that will do this, but have had no luck finding it thus far.

Example: `X-PRIVATE-TOKEN: We are the children of Korn!`

So that I can trust the `x-forwarded-for` address is the actual address, as opposed to simply distrusting all proxy request's ip address references.

Comment: I know this question is probably as equally relevant to ServerFault, however given that manually tweaking Web.config is more typical of the developer's domain, figured this would be the best place to actually get an answer here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try:

```
<rule name="myRule_01">
  ...
  <serverVariables>
    <set name="HTTP_X_PRIVATE_TOKEN" value="We are the children of Korn!" />
  </serverVariables>
  ...
</rule>
```

The header field of the http request will be: x-private-token

Answer (score 22):

The answer, courtesy of [IIS.net](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Note_about_request_headers_) , would appear to be that this is part of the related URL Rewrite Module:

> The request headers are set by using the same mechanism as for server
>   variables, but with a special naming convention. If a server variable
>   name in the  collection starts with "HTTP_" then this
>   results in an HTTP request header being set in accordance to the
>   following naming convention:
>
> All underscore ("_") symbols in the name are converted to dash symbols
>   ("-"). All letters are converted to lower case. "HTTP_" prefix is
>   removed For example the following configuration is used to sets the
>   custom x-original-host header on the request:
>
> `<set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />`

Comment: Holy crap this is convoluted but it works. Thank you so much 7 years later!