# Determine current page url when using off box SSL termination

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl

How can you determine the current request URL if using off box SSL termination?

E.g.

1. Browser has url `httpS://yourserver/`
2. SSL Termination decrypts and sends onto `http://yourserver`
3. IIS/ASP.NET receives request at `http://yourserver`

At (3) if you use `Context.Request.Url`, `Page.Request.Url` or `Page.Request.RawUrl` it show a  url with a http protocol and not httpS

How do get the public httpS URL that was origionally used at (1)  in this case?

Comment: I am aware of things like relative and protocol-relative url's but they won't help in this particular case.

Comment: Your proxy could add an HTTP header for offloaded SSL connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convention used for Microsoft Products is to add a header at the reverse proxy.

[Front-End-Https : On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

So you know the http url is really https.

You could also add in your own header containing the original URL if you did something like URL translation (e.g. something like "Original-Uri").

[This page](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables) shows how to do this using IIS AAR as the reverse proxy, though in my testing I could only get headers to pass through if they are [prefixed with HTTP_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590027/adding-a-custom-header-to-arr-requests) (which is later stripped out).