# IIS adding proxy header fails

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15899420/4965515), I added server variable "HTTP_X_PRIVATE_TOKEN" -> "1234" in order to a the header "x-private-token". But when I visit the URL of my webapp, I get an error 500 from ISS ("There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.")
The first question is why?? The second question is where can I find more info about the error the occurred (i.e. IIS logs)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the answer stated, one just need to create the server variable beforehand. This is done by going to the site -> Url rewrite -> View server variables -> Add...