# How can we set proxy headers in IIS rewrite module (equivalent to nginx proxy_pass)

Tags: nginx, iis, proxy, reverse-proxy, proxypass

How can we set proxy headers in IIS rewrite module

In nginx we have something like

```
server {
    location / {
        # we add a custom-host parameter in the header
        # which corresponds to the domain for which the certificates can be viewed
      proxy_set_header custom-host your-domain.com;
      proxy_pass https://certificate-testsite.com;
    }
}
```

What is equivalent to that in IIS. How we can set proxy header (custom-host) in IIS? I have tried using URL rewrite module and set serverVariables like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://certificate-testsite.com/{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_custom_host" value="your-domain.com" />
                    </serverVariables> 
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <rewriteMaps>
                <rewriteMap name="HTTP_custom_host" />
            </rewriteMaps>       
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But that doesn't work.
Thanks

Comment: Line by line translation can only lead you to the dead end. Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Did the reverse proxy fail?

Comment: Nope reverse proxy works fine, just the custom header value is not sent for some reason.

Comment: You need to set HTTP_custom_host as an allowed server variable for the site or machine.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Allowed_Server_Variables_List

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact equivalent in IIS, after all IIS and NGINX are different web servers with different configuration syntax and functionality. If you want to implement similar functionality on IIS, you may consider using the ARR module and URL Rewrite module. ARR allows you to enable a reverse proxy, and the URL Rewrite module allows you to create reverse proxy rules and set server variables.

In IIS, the serverVariables collection allows you to access server-specific variables. However, it is important to note that changes made to server variables in the server environment may not be directly reflected in the request headers visible in the client browser.

Reference links：

[Setting HTTP request headers and IIS server variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables)

[Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing)

[Adding a custom header to ARR requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590027/adding-a-custom-header-to-arr-requests)

Comment: Have tried all of these, using ARR module and URL rewrite (setting up server variables etc) but still doesn't work, Reverse proxy works fine, it just doesn't send custom header for some reason.